# What steps does the compiler follow when building and running ASP.NET Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am completely new to C# and ASP.NET (am experienced in Python/Flask) and was handed legacy code (with no documentation, comments or other developers to ask questions to) to try and debug. While trying to build an application, I got a

```
Server Error in '/' Application. There is no row at position 0.
```

From another stack overflow post, I found out this is a database error. However, I'm not sure which of the many files in the solution has the DB connection.

The project here is able to compile, but returns the above error when I go to the homepage. Where in the solution would I be able to find the file handling the routing? From searching the web, it seems like it should be in a file called Global.asax, but I don't see it in the solution. If Global.asax is not in the solution, when you type in F5 in Visual Studio, what file is being looked at to generate the home page content.

Comment: Have you tried searching the project for "database" or "db"?

Comment: @mjwills you're right, I incorrectly worded this question, it is a runtime error. Do you know which file handles the routing? There isn't anything called database or db in here.

Comment: Is this ASP.NET WebForms? ASP.NET MVC? ASP.NET Core?

Comment: I'm not sure. How would I find this out? I don't believe it's MVC as I don't see any folder for model, view, or controllers.